# Centralise 2nd item in row of 3

Tags: css

I have a row of 3 elements with the first floated left and the third floated right, how do I make the second one float central between the other 2?

All of the elements will be dynamic width so can't put a set margin

My example is at http://jsfiddle.net/S5fA3/

```
<div class="col-md-12 tags">
  <a class="tag" href="/">Lorem</a>
  <a class="tag" href="/">Dolorsitamet</a>
  <a class="tag" href="/">ipsum</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/S5fA3/1/)

**CSS**

```
.tags {
 padding:15px;
    text-align: center; /*center them all */
}
.tags a.tag {
 display: inline-block; /* change to inline-block*/
 font-size:16px;
 height:40px;
 padding:9px 15px;
 text-decoration:none;
 width:auto;
}
.tags a.tag:nth-child(1) { /* float first left */
  float:left;
}
.tags a.tag:nth-child(3n) { /* float last right */
 float:right;
}
.tags {
 background:#55616F;
}
.tags a.tag {
 background:#93A1AF;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to dip your feet into CSS3, have a look at the new flexbox specification. It works perfectly, albeit it being unsupported in old browsers (vendor prefixes are available for slightly less outdated browsers):

```
.tags {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 15px;
}
.tags a.tag {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: auto;
    /* Can be concatenated into shorthand:
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    */
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tags {
    background: #55616F;
}
.tags a.tag {
    background: #93A1AF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/S5fA3/2/

Comment: gone with Paulie's answer but this might help someone looking for a CSS3 option, thanks for the answer :)